# Servlet/JSP Error Pages

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee

I'm just looking for some advice on the use case scenarios for creating your own error pages. I've been experimenting with creating error pages and mapping them to codes, and it seems extremely simple to do, yet I've noticed a lot of web sites that don't bother, they simply rely own the browser default. I'm curious as to whether or not there is a standard or set of guidelines for which apporach is best? For such a simple feature, it's extremely underused imho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Desolate: Best approach is single error page strategy for any kind of exception/error happened at server side with error message: "Some error occurred, please contact customer care at [phone no]/[email] with error code: [error code].

This error code should be searchable in server log files which would give information about timestamp when error happened, user request, user data etc which will help support to investigate.